# Create minidump from Excel XLL

Tags: winapi, dll, crash

I have an Excel XLL addin that crashes Excel on some computers. 
In order to troubleshoot I added this call in `DllMain`:

```
SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(MyExceptionFilter);
```

and a filter itself:

```
LONG WINAPI MyExceptionFilter(struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *lpTopLevelExceptionFilter)
```

But filter never gets called on crash.

Comment: Excel probably overrides that itself somewhere - maybe you can use `OutputDebugString()` to get some diagnostics out to `DebugView` or similar?

Comment: I am doing a patch like in example here http://www.debuginfo.com/examples/src/debugfilters/EnforceFilter.cpp

Comment: Ok, but what if Excel did the same thing before it loaded your XLL? I don't know if it does, but it's one possible reason why your filter might not get called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question, but just in case this can help somebody else: using `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter()` inside XLLs is not supported by design, quoting a Microsoft employee Jie Wang from http://www.office-forums.com/threads/setunhandledexceptionfilter-in-office-addin.2164345/

> The behavior you observed is by design.
>
> 3rd-party addins/dlls cannot set the unhandled exception filter for Office
>   2007 apps (at least not in a supported way). MSO.DLL explicitly sets the
>   filter itself, then overrides the API to prevent 3rd-parties for changing
>   the filter after MSO has set it. It is common to all the Office apps (not
>   just Outlook).

So the only officially supported method of getting crash dumps from Excel is to use [WER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513641.aspx).

In practice, using MSVC-specific `_set_se_translator()` function does work however. But it must be called from all application threads, unlike the process-global `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter()`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But unfortunately even _set_se_translator did not not work for me for Excel addin.

Comment: FWIW I didn't have to do anything special to make it work. But there could be a difference in Excel versions, platforms, 32 vs 64 bits, so maybe it doesn't work in all combinations of those.

Comment: I tested on Excel 2013. 32 bit. What was your setup?

Comment: I _think_ I tested with 2013 too. I definitely did test with 2010, which was the most widely used version for my clients back then. Both in 32 bits.

Comment: /EHa flag and the error I tried was just addressing through null pointer like this  *( ( int* ) 0 ) = 0;